# Simple If Else Statement.

Tags: image, upload

Trying to get this to work.. I don't understand the If else Statement. Basically if the Field Photo has a value I would like it to display if it has a value of Null Obviously the Else Statement woudl display.

```
$row = photo

$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu_category WHERE id  = '$id' order by sort";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

echo " <h1>".$row['category_field']."</h1> ";
echo "<div class=\"itemdescription\">  ".$row['description']."</div> ";

$row = photo("*");

if ($photo = "*") {
echo "Have a good day!";
} else {
echo "Have a good night!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use !empty to check if the photo exist or not, not *

```
   $row = photo

$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu_category WHERE id  = '$id' order by sort";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$photo_exist = $row['photo'];

echo " <h1>".$row['category_field']."</h1> ";
echo "<div class=\"itemdescription\">  ".$row['description']."</div> ";



if (!empty($photo_exist)) {
echo "Have a good day!";
} else {
echo "Have a good night!";
}
```

Comment: I get an error on $id = $_GET['id']; with $row = photo above it.

Comment: the 2 error is cause by the $_GET should have @ before it, and the second due to no ";" at the end. however, u should delete the line $row = photo (it serve no purpose) but if u insist to have it, then it should be: $row = 'photo';  $id=@$_GET['id'];